# SSRS NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED Error in Google Chrome for HTTPS

Tags: windows, ssl, reporting-services, ssl-certificate, ssrs-2012

Please suggest  on the issue which we are facing while accessing SSRS Secured web services and web portal URL Error Message

> "Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal
>   your information from <> (for example, passwords, messages, or credit
>   cards). Learn more NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED"

We have got the SSL certificate reinstalled and restarted the SSRS services , but still no luck .
Could anyone please guide us in this regard Server configuration details are as follows -

-Microsoft SQL Server Version 17 
-SSRS product version of 14.0.600.490 
-WINDOWS SERVER 2016 DATACENTER

The SSL certificate is configured on Windows server .Also the SSL is configured in Web services and Web portal SSL configuration in SSRS is with (ALL IPV4) and (ALL IPV6),SSL certificate and validity till 2019

There was a patch update last week and post that we are unable to access secured urls 
https://<>/reports/ 
https://<>/reportserver/

but we can access non secured urls 
http://<>/reports/ 
http://<>/reportserver/

Comment: Any suggestion is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If the site is publicly accessible, please check the certificate served by your web server via [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html).

> Compare the certificate serial number and expiration date with the data of the certificate you installed in your web server or hosting control panel. In many cases, I saw that the server uses an old or invalid certificate.

([Source](https://port135.com/2019/02/09/error_internet_sec_cert_revoked/))

If you are sure that the correct certificate is served, clear the CRL and OCSP cache:

```
certutil -urlcache CRL delete
certutil -urlcache OCSP delete
```

You can also try disabling certificate revocation in browsers. It fixes ERR_CERT_REVOKED on the client side.